# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I want to update ADT Plugin in my eclipse. I did all as in [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#troubleshooting). But getting error as below,

[image]

**Error Message:**

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.java 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1329999971888 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1329999971888)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.java 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
    Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.java 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1329999971888 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1329999971888)
    To: epp.package.java [1.3.2.20110218-0812]
```

If anybody came across this, help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.5.0/ from installed software location. Now error is cleared. But **i do not know this is the right fix**. But i am `frequently facing this issue with eclipse when updating the software`. as for now, i have removed that one. If any one knows right solution please update.